# Having trouble getting browsers to cache content

Tags: http, caching, browser, apache2, cache-control

Sorry that this appears to be very similar to a number of other questions, but I have looked at all related posts I can see, but they don't seem to have quite the same issue as I do ;-)

The problem is that I can't get clientside caching of .js, .css and images to work from my Apache2 servers (I've got both Ubuntu Apache/2.2.8 and a WAMP Apache under Windows).

With default settings, I get good ETag style server-led caching (304 responses) but if I turn this off by putting Header Unset commands into my virtual host config file, and then supplement with Caching directives (see below), it doesn't seem to be respected by the browser.

I can see using Firebug that the browser knows that a cached file is valid for another couple of hours, but it still asks for it anyway.

Any tips on how to debug this would be most welcome.

The relevant part of host config is shown below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Projects/A2C/branches/CR7"
    ServerName *
    ServerAlias localhost ecomsvr0.dmclub.net
    ErrorLog "c:\log\a2c.log"
    CustomLog "c:\log\a2c-access.log" common
   <Directory "c:\projects\A2C\branches\CR7">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride all
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    ExpiresDefault A36000
    Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=7200"
    Header Unset Etag
    Header Unset Last-Modified
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

What strikes me is that you don't send any validator (Last-Modified or ETag). While they are not mandatory, I strongly encourage you to send one, to enable browsers to do conditional requests. [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) says "HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD send Last-Modified whenever feasible." This must not be the root cause of your problem, but it could well be.

So I suggest to **remove the line "Header Unset Last-Modified"** and check again.

Note that your Expires is access time plus 36000s while your max-age time is 7200s, which doesn't make sense. Browsers understanding the new Cache-Control directive (all new browsers do) will go for max-age.

If adding Last-Modified does not work, can you please post the full response headers your server sends? For example, go to http://redbot.org/ and run this checker against your server and post the results. This will further help to identify your problem.

Comment: I deliberately removed the Last-Modified/ETag, because I don't want conditional requests - they're more expensive for us than having (say) a 1hr cache. Ideally we'd have both, but I understand that they don't work together at all well (which I guess is due to their independent nature). I'll try the redbot thing, though. Cheers.

Comment: Just tried redbot and found exactly the same response that Firebug showed me. The URL is http://ecom0.edge5.dmclub.net/test/integration/ajl/cachetest.html and my desire is to get simple client-side caching with no conditional requests (we're trying to reduce latency)

Comment: Thanks for posting the URL. Now my FF caches the response and serves it from cache without revalidation. The headers include both validators now (I assume you have since changed the config). Re conditional requests: they are only sent by browsers when the resource is not fresh anymore but still in the cache. So you shouldn't loose anything by adding a validator. If your backend cannot respond to conditional reuests with HTTP/304 (not modified), just return a normal 200 response.

Comment: THanks - I think we've tracked the source of our original concern down to the behaviour of the F5 button! Refreshing a page this way is different to pressing enter in the URL field.

Comment: I had heard, though, that returning a 304 can confuse the cache in some browsers - so that once the original object is stale, the browser will ask for a fresh copy and be given a 304 - and then do this EVERY TIME the resource is referenced in the page. Not sure what browsers would exhibit this behaviour, though.